# Open file and count how many times a word is in file

Tags: python

I want to open a file with a given word.  The function will read the file line by line and return a count of how many lines contain the given word.

```
def count_word(file_name, word):
  with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    line.rstrip('\n')
    cnt = 0
    for line in file:
      if word in line:
        cnt += 1
      return cnt
```

This is what I've tried, but it's not working correctly. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: your `return` is in your `for` loop

Comment: `it's not working correctly.` - can you be more specific? Do you have some test strings that you can test with, and share in your question? Please read [mcve]. Have you tried printing stuff at different places to help you see what is going on?

Comment: You have your `return cnt` inside the loop, so your function will exit after checking the second line of the file only.  A count greater than one is therefore impossible.  Unindent that line by one level.

Comment: Also, if a line contains the word multiple times the count is only incremented by 1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def count_word(file_name, word):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        return content.count(word)
```

Comment: it may count words which are part of other words - ie. `some` in word `someone`. It could be better to split text into list of words.

Answer (score 2):

You need to count the occurrences of the word in isolation. For example, `as` is in `classic`, but the word `as` does not appear in the sentence `this is a classic problem`. Additionally, you need to move your return to outside the for-loop:

```
def wordCount(infilepath, word):
    answer = 0
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for line in infilepath:
            answer += line.split().count(word)
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version using `collections.Counter` and `re.split`:

```py
from collections import Counter
import re

def count_word(file_name, word):
    return Counter(re.split('\s+|\W+', open(file_name).read())).get(word, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, first, it loads the file, then looks through it and counts up all of the words in each line and returning them

```
#function to count words
def count_word(file_name, word):
    #hold number of words
    cnt = 0
    #open file
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        #get lines
        lines = file.readlines()
        #loop the thrpugh file
        for line in lines:
            #strip the line
            line.rstrip('\n')
            #get how many times it appears in the line
            cnt += line.lower().split().count(word)
    return cnt


print(count_word("test.txt", "test"))
```